# Best way of displaying error messages of an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have the following problem:

I have a textbox where I take the value of the textbox on hitting the enter button and I want to catch the error that no name is present. so I added this to my model:

```
validates :name, presence: true
```

In my controller I only changed what should happen if saving it succeeds:

```
def create
  @role = Role.new(role_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @role.save
      format.js { render :created }
    else
      format.json { render json: @role.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

and my JavaScript file has this function:

```
$(function(){
  $("body").on("keyup", "#role_name", function(e){
    if ( e.which == 13 ) {
      role_name = $("#role_name").val();
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "script",
      url: '/roles',
      data: {role: {name: role_name} },
      success: function(){
        $("#role_name").val("");
        $("#alert-new-role").replaceWith("<div id='alert-new-role' class='alert alert-success col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1'><strong>role created!</strong></div>");
        }
      }).fail(function(){
        $("#alert-new-role").replaceWith("<div id='alert-new-role' class='alert alert-danger col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1'><strong>name can't be empty!</strong></div>");

      });
    }
  });
})
```

this actually works, but my error messages are hardcoded. Should I ever add a 2nd validation rule I can't tell what exactly caused the error.

Firebug is showing me the JSON that was created by the controller but somehow I can't access it inside the .fail function from jQuery.

I checked all 4 parameters but none contains my error message.

I found several examples how it should be done, but somehow I can't reproduce it.

If I can access the JSON, it would also be an idea to render a partial in rails and pass it to back to the .fail function.

Comment: The *best way* can depend on how you've been taught, this might be classed as opinionated.

Comment: you are right, I'll keep this in mind next time. thank you. I'll also write should correctly from now on, hopefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I use and should be easy enough to expand on with an array of html warnings and a switch statement on `error` or just one html string with inserted values from the error:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "page.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function() {},
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
      console.log(err.Message);
      console.log('xhr: ');
      console.log(xhr);
      console.log('status: ' + status);
      console.log('error: ' + error);
    }
  });
```

You can access the data you want via the xhr object within the error function which will be something like the below (right click and open image in new tab for a better look):

[image]

Comment: looks like the error message is ineed inside the responseText field. I just was overwhelmed by the amount of objects inside xhr and didn't check everyone of them. now it is only a matter how I access the JSON, but I'll figure it out. thank you alot.

Comment: You can access it via the `xhr` object within the error function

Comment: yea I know, I meant how I handle the JSON in jquery, haven't dealt with them alot until now.